# Using new microsoft-graph-auth library java sdk gives unauthorized error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

[Permissions in azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd5HQ.png) I am trying to use microsoft graph auth library preview. [Microsoft-graph-auth-sdk-java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth) I am able to initialize the graphClient but unable to get data.I am getting unauthorized 401.

> "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
>       "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",

```
 List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.add("User.Read.All");

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(app-Id, 
            scopes_list,
            client-Secret,
            tenantId, NationalCloud.Global);

IgraphClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).logger(logger)
                .buildClient();

IUserCollectionPage users = graphClient.users()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
    List<User> usersList = users.getCurrentPage();
    for(User user : usersList) {
        System.out.println(user.displayName);
    }
```

[Permissions picture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/segmO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions and code are fine. The issue must be with the library since it is in snapshot. But I guess they recently made some changes which could have fixed the issue you are facing. Try re-building the jar from the project.

Answer (score 1):

For making app-only calls using client credentials you will need to pass the scope "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" and then in the app registration portal grant admin consent for User.Read.All.

Comment: `List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
  scopes.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");`
`List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
  scopes.add(".default");`

I tried with above two approaches. I have the permissions granted admin consent. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you parsed your token to see if it has the permissions in it? You can parse tokens at https://jwt.ms

Comment: Can anyone share the working code or can reproduce my issue? What I am trying to say If you are using msgraph-sdk-java-auth then one should not worry about getting tokens. As you pass client-id , secret, scopes to ClientCredentialsProvider and use this to directly initialize you graph client.

Comment: @AbhishekKumbhaj Can you show a screenshot of the granted permissions in the portal?  You need to grant the application permission and not the delegated permission?

Comment: @DarrelMiller I have added permissions picture link in question. I build the JAR from source code available on GitHub. Where can I find the updated JAR? Can you reproduce the issue or can share the code that works?
[permissions link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/segmO.png)

Comment: Apart from InvalidAuthenticationToken I am getting: 

`OAuthProblemException{error='unsupported_response_type', description='Invalid response! Response body is not application/json encoded', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}
 at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:63)
 at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.setBody(OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.java:76)
 at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.j`